# How can I create a square hextilemap?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have this code:

```
            int tX = 1;

            for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < tX; x++)
                {
                    Tile t = new Tile()
                    {
                        Texture = tile,
                        Position = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point(x, y),
                        Troops = rnd.Next(1, 4),
                        OwnedByPlayerIndex = 0
                    };
                    t.Tap += tile_Tap;

                    if (t.Position.Y < ROWS)
                        tiles.Add(t);
                }
                tX += 2;

                tX = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(tX, 0, COLS);
            }
```

And what im trying to do is create a map within a rect, limiting the map by number of rows and cols.

But it does not work as it does not follow up and finishes the last corner, leaving it uncomplete

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have some redudant logic in there, and your inner loop is not iterating over all columns.  If you want to fill the entire rectangle then you don't need tX at all.  Example:

```
for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++)
    {
        Tile t = new Tile()
        {
            Texture = tile,
            Position = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point(x, y),
            Troops = rnd.Next(1, 4),
            OwnedByPlayerIndex = 0
        };
        t.Tap += tile_Tap;
        tiles.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Additionally, from your screenshot it looks like if the entire bottom row were filled then the lower staggered hexes would overlap the bottom of the red rectangle.  If you don't want to add those lower hexes then you'll need to add them conditionally:

```
...
if (y > 0 || 0 == (x & 1))
    tiles.Add(t);
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. with hex tiles you cant think of it like a regular 2d array. so iterating x and y like in a 2d array will not work

Comment: Coordinates for hex tiles are represented exactly the same as for rectangular tiles: (row, column) or (column, row).  The only difference is that when you display them you must offset odd-numbered columns vertically by half the height of the hex, and less than a full hex width is used to separate the columns horizontally.  Additional logic is needed to calculate adjacencies, but that doesn't apply in this case.  A grid of X columns by Y rows will have the same logical structure for either rectangular tiles or hexagonal tiles.

Comment: I think you will get a problem finding your neighbour in a easy way thinking in 2d array with hex tiles